# Proof of discontinuity of function

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

I have found one proof of discontinuity with $\delta - \epsilon$, but I don't understand one inequality. So let $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$g(x):= \begin{cases}
x^2-3 & \text{if} \quad x\leq0 \newline
\sin(x) & \text{if} \quad x>0
\end{cases}$

Proof that $g$ is discontinuous at 0.

Let $\epsilon=2$ and let $\delta>0$ be given. Choose $x \in (0,\delta)$ with $x<\pi$. Then $g(x)=\sin(x)>0$. Hence,

$|x-0|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(0)|=|\sin(x)-3|>3 \geq \epsilon$. But why $|\sin(x)-3|>3$???? Since $\sin(x)>0$, $|\sin(x)-3|$ can not be greater than 3. If $\quad$ $\sin(x)<0$, then it will work. But since $\sin(x)>0$ its impossible. Can somebody explain me this?

Comment: You are right, this proof is not correct. Replace $>3$ by $\ge2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you :)